# Placing image above div pushes content in other places

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an image above the top bar of a div on my website on the left side of where the navigation bar is. [My Attempt](http://justmyshit.com/shaunmichael/)

It should look [Like this](http://justmyshit.com/shaunmichael/index2.html)

And I would like it to look [Like this](http://justmyshit.com/shaunmichael/sitefix.jpg)

I've tried multiple things such as placing the div for the image in different spots in the code, and changing css elements for the div, but everything seems to push the other content images out of place on the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this ...

```
.photo {
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
}
```

and change the margin on #container to...

```
#container {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Works great, but is there a way to remove that gap between the bottom of the picture and the border of the div, so that it sits on top of it like the navigation bar?  http://justmyshit.com/shaunmichael/

Comment: @syllable3 Move the `line-height:150%;` property from your body to the UL, or add `line-height:100%;` to the photo div.

Comment: my css above shifts the photo down 4px, that did not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your css isn't in very good shape, but, using your methods here's how to do it:

1. remove the `margin-top` from `#container`
2. add `vertical-align: top` to the `img` inside `#photo`
3. change the `top` in `#extraDiv1` to `246px`
4. change the `top` in `.horizontal` to `218px`

I guess that should do it.